# Download MacOS install disc?

Tags: install

My MacBook Pro doesn't boot anymore. I've lost my install disc for the OS and I need to format/re-install. What are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to an Apple store or Apple reseller and purchase the Snow Leopard install DVD.  It's relatively inexpensive (as far as Operating System prices are concerned).

Here is the [link](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A?fnode=MTY1NDAzOA&mco=MTM3NDgwNzM) to the online store, where it will ship within 24 hours.

Comment: Many apple stores are set up for a rapid net install restore that takes 5 to 25 minutes based on load and your mac's speed. Also, ordering replacement media may be less expensive than the retail DVD.

Comment: very true.  In my case, I'd be so desperate to get going again, I'd be busting down the doors of my Apple store than waiting for a shipment :)